# how can I get the menubar background color fit to the page?

Tags: html, css

how can I get rid of the white spaces in the corners if I want the menubar background color fit to the page?

I tried changing the page width to 100% but nothing seems to be changing.

any help would be appreciated!

here is a link:

[http://scratchpad.io](http://scratchpad.io/amazing-hammer-745)

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

#menubar {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menubar ul li {
  display: inline;
}

#menubar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubar">
  <div id="menubar-container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Services</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in your css.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: The question owner has updated the question. There was no "body" tag in HTML or no css for "body" at the beginning.  So I provided the solution using * 

now:

`body {
    margin: 0;
}`
should work fine !!!

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use dev tools https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

```
body {
 margin: 0;
}
```